# How to render Wireframe for the entire scene not just one object?

Tags: wireframe

Sorry if this is a daft question but in all the tutorials I've watched it just shows how to do a wireframe for one object not an entire scene and I don't really fancy having to select every single object and apply the wireframe mod to it. I know about the wireframe material that I could apply to the scene but that displays it in triangles and I want it in Quads.

Answer (score 1):

Here how would I do this task.

1. Get 2.8x version
2. Set up overlays like this:

[image]

3. When setup matcap and cavity as you want:

[image]

[image]

4. If the result is not bad, click **View** -> **Viewport render**.
5. If you want wireframe on top of Cycles (or outer) Render Setup viewport like this:

[image]

[image]

6. In **color management** set **View transform** to **default**

[image]

7. When  click **View** -> **Viewport render** and compose resulted image over render using multiply.

Comment: @JoshuaLord Please do not add a comment on your question or on an answer to say "Thank you". Comments are meant for requesting clarification, leaving constructive criticism, or adding relevant but minor additional information – not for socializing. If you want to say "thank you," vote on or accept that person's answer https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

Quick script nothing fancy just uncomment set or removed at bottom and run for 2.79.
Note that removing the wireframe modifier will not discriminate if there were some you wanted to leave in place.

```
import bpy

objects = bpy.context.scene.objects


def set_wired():
    for ob in objects:
        if ob.type == 'MESH':
            objects.active = ob
            bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='WIREFRAME')


def rem_wired():
    for ob in objects:
        if ob.type == 'MESH':
            objects.active = ob
            try:
                bpy.ops.object.modifier_remove(modifier="Wireframe")
            except:
                print('no wireframe modifier on %s' % ob.name)

set_wired()
#rem_wired()
```

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but I don't think there is a way to do that normally in Blender, but if you program Python (unless someone might be willing to whip up a quick script for you), I think you should be able to modify this script to do exactly what you're looking for...

https://en.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Render/Clay_Render

Answer (score 0):

Once you have your wireframe material created just set in in the Materials box

[image]

This is how I created all the clay/wire videos here
https://youtu.be/Q6FS9sRJcDQ?t=48

and the Python if you need to automate it.

```
bpy.context.scene.render.layers["RenderLayer"].material_override = bpy.data.materials["MYMATERIALNAME"]
```