# Rendering as wireframe only

Tags: rendering, wireframe

I need a simple *wireframe only* render with a white background.

Any tips on how I could get it?

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/9177/wireframe-render-over-an-object-with-the-subdivision-surface-wireframe and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38384/render-wireframes-with-hidden-wires and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23616/how-to-render-as-only-wireframe-in-cycles and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/9271/render-a-wireframe-with-equal-thickness-in-cycles and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/124721/how-to-render-wireframe-for-the-entire-scene-not-just-one-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Set the horizon to white
2. Turn on freestyle
3. Set freestyle visibilty to QI Range
4. Set the objects material fully transparent.

[image]